# How to show latest record for line chart when page loads?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying create script, where whenever, the page loads, it always renders the line and table chart, showing latest date data.

I have created the following code and assigned it to each of the charts state property and I am failing to get my desired output on the client-side:

****** Updated Code: ******

```
        var latestDate = data.getColumnRange(5).max;

        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            containerId: 'table_div',
            chartType: 'Table',
            options: {

            },
            'state': {
                'value': [latestDate]
            }

        });
```

Is there a better approach to carry out this task.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Don´t format it, google chart api works with values, and displays formattedValues so using a formatted value with `selectedValues` will never work. So: `var latestDate = data.getColumnRange(5).max;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation, into where I was going wrong.  I made the necessary changes (pls see updated above), but the table is still not showing the latest record of data, on the client-side. Please advice further.  Thank you

Comment: `ChartWrapper` does not have a state option, could you show your full `drawChart()` code? Not sure what are you trying to do with the latest date

Comment: Apology for not making my question clearer.  Here is my entire API code: http://jsfiddle.net/miss/2c1djqu9/.  my goal is, when the page loads, the line and table only show data from the latest date.   Is this plausible with my dataset?  Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty extensive, but here is the main idea:

```
        data = response.getDataTable();

        var latestDate = data.getColumnRange(5).max; // get latest date
        var dataview = new google.visualization.DataView(data); // create dataview to filter rows

        dataview.setRows(dataview.getFilteredRows([{column:5, value: latestDate}])) // filter rows by latest date value

        console.log(dataview.getDistinctValues(5)) // shows only latest date
```

Then you can set this dataView to the dashboard